# Zurb Foundation (with jsFiddle) why does row height of empty divs/cells not match rest of row?

Tags: zurb-foundation

In the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/carled/bu2Dw/  I would expect (and would like!) to see the two side cells ("small-2 columns menuHeader") that are empty match the height of the entire row. Why does this not happen please?

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-2 columns menuHeader">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="small-8 columns menuHeader">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-4 columns text-left">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80&text=Image 1" />
                    </div>
                <div class="small-4 columns text-left">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80&text=Image 2" />
                    </div>
                <div class="small-4 columns text-left">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80&text=Image 3" />
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="small-2 columns menuHeader">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Much experimentation led to just encasing it in a 12-column div, which works fine:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns menuHeader">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-2 columns">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="small-8 columns">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-4 columns text-left">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80&text=Image 1" />
                            </div>
                        <div class="small-4 columns text-left">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80&text=Image 2" />
                            </div>
                        <div class="small-4 columns text-left">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80&text=Image 3" />
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="small-2 columns">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: maybe you could also add a class to empty columns `empty` and then set the height to those columns in `onload`. I personally had a similar problem, but needed no background effect, so I got away with defining an empty class `empty {min-height: 1px;}`. That way you won't need an extra wrapper row nor putting `&nbsp;` into empty columns.

Comment: Yup, it's an option. At the time I was keen to keep the css "vanilla" and not add my own sprinkles to it ;-)